# How to run code after all Testfixture - Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

My Nunit/Selenium setup is currently creating a test report (Using ExtentReport). I want this test report to be send via email when all the testfixtures are run. How can i do this?

I have tried using the "OneTimeTearDown" within the TestFixture class, but this runs the code every time a TestFixture has been completed. I currently have 20 test cases each run in both Chrome TestFixture & IE11. So by using this method, I would end up with 40 mails in my inbox.

Answer (score 2):

To run an action at the end of the test run, you can use a `OneTimeTearDown` in a `SetUpFixture` outside of any namespace. See the docs [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute).

I wouldn't recommend doing this within your test assembly however - feels to me like something which should be scripted into your CI process instead. That's your decision to make, however. :-)